# Basic Hashtable algorithm - removing duplicates

Tags: duplicates, hashtable

I just had an interview this morning and I was given the question "Give an algorithm for removing duplicates from a list of integers".  This is a fairly standard question so I was pretty confident I could answer it.

I am paraphrasing, but I said something along the lines of "You could use a hashtable. Start with the first integer and insert it into the hashtable.  Then for each successive integer do a hashtable lookup to check if the integer is already in the hashtable, if not then insert it, if its already there then throw it away because it is a duplicate.  So iterate though the list in this way.  If the hashtable is designed correctly, the lookups and inserts should be constant time on average."

Then the interviewer responded (again I am paraphrasing) "But hashtable lookups are not constant time, they depend on how many elements are already in it.  The algorithm you described would be O(n^2)"

Then I responded "Really? I thought that if you designed a good hash-function, it would be constant time? Making it O(n) typically"

Then the interviewer responded "So you are saying that the lookup time would be the same for a hash table with many entries and a hashtable with few entries"

Then I said "Yes.  If it is designed correctly."

Then the interviewer said "This is not true"

SO I am very confused right now.  If someone could point out where I am wrong, I would be very grateful

Comment: If these guys offer you a job, you should politely decline it.

Comment: Either the guy has no idea what he's talking about or he was seeing if you're knowledgeable enough to defend your case properly. The only thing I would've said differently - instead of "Yes. If it is designed correctly", I would've said "Asymptotically, yes, with a good hash function and assuming the hash table is large enough. Occasionally there may be collisions, but it should remain O(1).".

Comment: Oh, and beyond a good hash function, you also need well-distributed data. Even with the best hash function ever, there still exists a dataset where you will get many conflicts resulting in O(n) operations on the hash table. All in all, they may have wanted you to suggest sorting the data or they were simply thoroughly checking your understanding.

Comment: [Pathological](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/pathological) (worst) case is also a good term to know - "When used of test input, implies that it was purposefully engineered as a worst case. The implication in both senses is that the data is spectacularly ill-conditioned or that someone had to explicitly set out to break the algorithm in order to come up with such a crazy example."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If someone could point out where I am wrong

You are not wrong at all: properly designed hash tables gives you an expected lookup efficiency of `O(1)` and inserts in amortized `O(1)`, so your algorithm is `O(N)`. Lookup in heavily loaded hash tables is indeed a little slower because of possible duplicate resolution, but the expected lookup time remains `O(1)`. This may not be good enough for real-time systems where "amortized" does not count, but in all practical situations this is enough.

Of course you could always use a balanced tree for the items that you've seen for a worst-case `O(N*LogN)` algorithm, or if the numbers have reasonable bounds (say, between 0 and 100,000) you could use a boolean array to test membership in `O(1)` worst-case, and a potential improvement over a hash table because of a smaller constant multiplier.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought.  At one point, the interviewer even repeated what I had said so I know that he didn't hear me incorrectly.  I don't know how this is possible, its a fairly big company.

Comment: I think its important to note that the **expected** lookup time is O(1).  Regardless of the hash function you pick, the worst case is that you get unlucky and hit a conflict with **all** inserts causing O(n) lookup time.  This is true even with a universal hashing strategy.

Comment: @dbyrne You are right, expected vs. worst-case is a good thing to mention. Thanks!